# How to strip accents?

Tags: android, string, diacritics

I have an android app that takes an ISO8859-1 (Latin1) file with data.
Essentially, Portuguese words whose characters I want to convert to the un-accented counterparts.

Yes, I googled a lot for this, and tried the

```
      Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
```

trick, and yes, I tried also

```
      String.replaceAll("[áâã]", "a").replaceAll(....)....
```

but the string remains accented. I also tried messing with the project encodings, but not sure where to change (if this is a solution at all).

Comment: You know in Java strings are immutable and those functions generally return a new string, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. Just added "Latin1" when reading the InputStreamReader (it seems that, despite the config, it was assuming UTF-8 or something else).

So this is how I read the file now:

```
 br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(Environment.BR_DB), "Latin1"));
```

I needed to add an UnsupportedEncodingException.

Thanks for the previous answers,

```
L.
```

Answer (score 2):

Like auselen said...

Not

```
String.replaceAll("[áâã]", "a").replaceAll(....)
```

But

```
value = String.replaceAll("[áâã]", "a").replaceAll(....)
```

[Edit]

Don't use the string class as the object to replace... i just tested this code and it executed perfectly...

```
String weirdAs = "ábâcdeã";

String newString = weirdAs.replaceAll("[áâã]", "a");

Toast.makeText(_context,
            "New String: " + newString + " Weird As: " + weirdAs,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[Edit 2]

Just for fun... here's a logcat output...

```
09-14 09:16:23.502: I/Test(12022): Original String (Weird As): ábâcdeã
09-14 09:16:23.502: I/Test(12022): New String: abacdea
```

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I should have been more explicit. I did newst = oldst.replaceAll(...)....

Comment: Yes, that also works for me. But not when reading from the file... Could be an encoding problem??

Comment: Yeah, check the encoding type... it's possible you ended up in a format that doesn't support your original character set. If you output what you read in (just put it in an edittext or textview or something if it's too long for logcat), does it show the characters as you expected it to?

Comment: Actually, what I see both in LogCat and in a TextView is a (twisted) square with a question mark inside instead of an "a" (expected value) or an "ã" (wrong, but expected). So it seems I need to change somewhere the encodings. My file is ISO88569-1 (Latin1). I set encoding to Latin1 in Window>Preferences>General>Workspace, and the problem persists. :(

Comment: If you open the file itself on your local machine (with text editor), does it show those characters? Was it saved from the start with the correct encoding?

Comment: Well, I don't really know. I am using an ADV emulator where I push the files through adb, so no text editors. All I know is that my original file is an ISO8859 files according to the 'file' command in linux. I used the following command to read the file, maybe it's this: br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(Environment.BR_DB)));